# Splash Screen Shared Element Transition On Bigger Screens

Tags: android-studio, splash-screen, shared-element-transition

I want to make a splash screen that appears when i open the app and disappears after 3 seconds, with the image being shared with the next activity.

On smaller screens(for example Pixel 2) the animation works without problems, but when i try it on my OnePlus 6 or Pixel 3 XL, the image always clips to like 50dp below it's position right before the transition.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem.

The issue was that i was setting a color on the splash screen's frame background. If i didn't set any color, it would work fine.

I found a way around it by adding a view that expanded the whole screen and setting the color to the view instead.

I hope this will help someone eventually.